# React Native. trying to load an image from url

Tags: image, react-native

I've managed to load an image from the web into my app but have an issue...

I have some local data about food.  each food item has a food title, and a url to a picture online.

This is the Image component that lives inside my foodComponent.

```
<Image style={styles.cardImg} source={{uri:image}} />
```

image is a string to a url that is passed as a prop to this foodComponent.

Again it works but my problem is that the image takes time to load.
How could I only render the foodItem component once it has received/loaded an image?

I know about promises but I don't see how I could use it in this scenario.

here is my entire foodItem component:

```
export default function FoodItemTouchable(props){
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.card}>

                <View style={styles.cardHeader}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{props.item.title}</Text>
                </View>

                <Break/>

                <CardImage image={props.item.url}/>

            </View>
        </View>
    )
}


function Break() {
    return(
        <View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
            <View style={styles.break}>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

function CardImage({image}){
    return(
        <View style={{padding:10,width:'100%'}}>
            <Image
                style={styles.cardImg}
                source={{uri:image}}
              />
        </View>
    )
}
```

CardImage is where the image gets rendered.
the rest of the Components render first but the CardImage is delayed because it's loading the image.

If I could somehow load the image into a variable in the main Component,
and then there do a check,   is image===null ? return null
so that the component renders only when the image is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this?

```
{
props.item.url
&&
<CardImage image={props.item.url}/>
}
```

Comment: Yes. I think the problem is, props.item.url   does exist, but only as a string,   once the program proceeds,  cardImage finally starts fetching the image. and takes a couple seconds to load it.      I was thinking about, what if I converted my images to base64,   and now I can save the image as a string to a const  in the FoodItem component.  which can also be passed to image, and it should render it immediately?